# SQL- Using lead with group by to get closest value for a group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, lead

I would like to use the Lead function to get the closest value for a group
Below is some sample data from  **flx_alps_boundaries**

| Subject code | Grade | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 1 | 1.12 |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 2 | 1.03 |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 3 | 0.97 |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 4 | 0.92 |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 5 | 0.86 |
| 20-BD-AC-AL | 6 | 0.84 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 1 | 1.15 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 2 | 1.10 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 3 | 1.05 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 4 | 1.00 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 5 | 0.98 |
| 20-BD-AH-AL | 6 | 0.96 |

I am calculating the score for a subject using a formula and getting the grade for the nearest matching score from the above table . eg if score is 0.95 for subject 20-BD-AC-AL the grade should be 4

This is my current sql

```
   select top 1 
          ab.alps_grade  as alps_grade,
          round( sum (actual_alps_points - expected_alps_points) 
                   / (count(reference) * 100)  + 1,2 ) as alps_score
   from   alps_cte 
   inner join [flx_alps_boundaries] ab 
           on alps_cte.course = ab.course_code
   where  ab.course_code in ('20-BD-AC-AL','20-BD-AH-AL')
   group by course,ab.alps_grade,ab.alps_score
   order by abs(round(sum(actual_alps_points 
                       - expected_alps_points) 
                       / (count(reference)*100)  + 1, 2) 
                       - ab.alps_score)
```

This query only returns one row. How do I use LEAD to get the appropriate grade for **each**
subject's score?

Comment: `This query only returns one row`. You have a `TOP 1` there, have you tried removing that ?

Comment: @Squirrel  When I remove the Top 1 from the sql I get several rows for each course code <br> What I need is 1 row per course code <br> The row I need for each code is the one with the appropriate grade for each course's score.<br> The order by clause puts the appropriate grades for each of the 2 courses  at the top of the list

Comment: use `row_number() over (partition by course_code order by somecol)` There are lots of similar question in this site